# How to remove (not modify) a request header in a Firefox addon?

Tags: http-headers, firefox-addon

I am using nsIHttpChannel in an observer to modify outgoing request headers, which works fine. According to the [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIHttpChannel#setEmptyRequestHeader()), however, it appears I cannot simply remove a header (as I can in Chrome), I can only give it an empty value via `setEmptyRequestHeader()`. Is there some other way to completely remove the header from the request ?

Comment: the docs you linked say *"If aValue is empty and aMerge is false, the header will be cleared."*, does that not do what you want?

Comment: Yes do setRequestHeader with undefined and merge false. @the8472 you should make that to solution.

Comment: Exactly right -- my bad reading skills. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `setRequestHeader()` states

> If aValue is empty and aMerge is false, the header will be cleared.